# Разработка нового сайта на ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Стоит ли переходит сейчас на VS 2014 и MVC 6 для создания нового сайта, или делать лучше на MVC 5 до выхода конечно релиза?

Как я понимаю VS 2014 с vNext выйдет не раньше лета 2015 года, но хотелось бы использовать возможности уже сейчас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о домашнем/тестовом проекте, то почему бы и нет - получите небесполезный опыт работы с новыми (и вполне перспективными) технологиями. Если же речь о "рабочем" проекте, то в 95% случаев лучше подождать официального релиза, появления полной и обширной документации, допиливания всех возможностей и устранения багов - рисковать стабильностью проекта ради использования новых (пусть и вкусных) возможностей не слишком разумно.

Comment: Речь идет о дипломном проекте. На который у меня год. Просто не нашел подробного объяснения можно ли будет потом перейти на vNext с минимальными изменениями MVC (только смог найти информацию что поменялся файл конфигурации и подключений, а про остальное как то все смутно) или придется переписывать все заново?

Comment: боюсь, конкретных рецептов относительно vNext я вам не назову (у самого к сожалению до него руки еще не дошли), однако для дипломного проекта, полагаю, vNext использовать вполне можно (хотя не факт, что нужно - все-таки диплом не предъявляет к себе каких-то завышенных бизнес-требований, и его без особых проблем можно написать и на текущих версиях фреймворка)